# DataTransfer an image from same page gives URL but image from different page gives file

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT**

The source of this problem is the behavior of the Edge browser, as identified by Sami. Firefox does the same thing, but Chrome works fine.

**Original Question**

I have a drop container for users to drag and drop an image to set an `<input type="file">` with the image.

If the image is being dragged and dropped from a different page, the image is recognized as a file. However, if the image is dragged and dropped from the same page with the drop container, it is recognized as a URL.

**Why isn't the image being recognized as a file when it is dragged and dropped from the same page as the drop container?**

Here is the fiddle with the drop container and image file. When you drag the image file on this page into the drop container, it is recognized as a URL although I want it to be recognized as a file.

https://jsfiddle.net/nadf9c82/1/

Next, try dragging the image on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7sqb5r0f/1/ into the drop container on the other fiddle and you will see it is recognized as a file, which is what I want.

Why do images on the same page as the drop container evaluate as URLs and not files? Is there a fix to make them recognized as files and not URLs?

Here is the code for reference

```
<div class="dropContainer" id="dropContainer">Drop Here</div>
```

```
<div id="imagetwo">
   <img src="http://a.mktgcdn.com/p/khxNbcdQcr1HQKNgk9cPNUyWUprmZ5Dryx9P5MAV0SE/2669x3840.jpg" />
</div>
<script>
dropContainer.ondrop = function(evt) {
  //evt.preventDefault();
  if(evt.dataTransfer.files[0]){
    console.log("is a file");
    const dT = new DataTransfer();
    dT.items.add(evt.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    fileInput.files = dT.files;
  }else{
    // Try dataTransfer url second
    var dataTransferUrl = evt.dataTransfer.getData('url');
    if(dataTransferUrl){
      console.log('is a url, not a file');
      console.log(dataTransferUrl);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tested both of the fiddles with Chrome (v. 96.0.4664.110) and Edge (v. 97.0.1072.55) and on the Chrome both fiddles work just fine and the image is recognized as a file. However when using Edge, the issue you described is present and the image on the same page as the drop container is identified as an URL.

Comment: Interesting, I am using Edge so that makes sense. Any reason why Edge does this and are there any work arounds?

Comment: Second finding: If you insert the image src as Data URI, the drag and drop works on edge too. This is quite interesting. Edge handles the images from within the page as URLs, which seems to be the default behaviour. Sadly, I have no idea how to fix it :(

Comment: Note that on macOS both Chrome and Firefox behave the same: they do prevent the file from being accessible in the DT. That sounds quite sensible given the image is from a different origin, and offering it as a File would allow your page to read its content. Also, you don't need to create a new DataTransfer object, your `evt.dataTransfer` is already one, so simply do `input.files = evt.dataTransfer.files` and you win 5 years of browser support in Chrome and Safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it, but it won't work in `Fiddle` due to `The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource ... the content must be served over HTTPS` due to your `HTTP` request

Here's what I think, whenever you drop the image, it'll receive an URL instead of the file like you want. Then just make it into a file.

It's called convert your `URL image to File object`, if my way is not working, it's the keyword for you to have a look more, I hope it'll give you some ways to work around since I'm not good at this, too.

Replace this code of mine into your  `Try dataTransfer URL second` part, but be warned that it'll fire an error on `Fiddle` due to `HTTP` request. So I've to replace the `HTTP` with `HTTPS`, but it'll get you the `CORS Block`, so if you have the extension to `unblock CORS`, it'll work, for development or testing purposes, of course.

```
    let url = evt.dataTransfer.getData('url');

    const urlArray = Array.from(url)
    urlArray.splice(4, 0, 's')
    const urlFinal = urlArray.join('')

    fetch(urlFinal)
        .then(async (res) => {
            const contentType = await res.headers.get('Content-Type')
            const blob = await response.blob()
            const file = new File([blob], "image.jpeg", { contentType })
        })
  }
```

When I drop an image to `Drop Here` box, it'll create an `Object File`, so it'll count as a file instead of an URL, I think that's what you want, hope I can help you somehow.

***Take an URL as an Object File after Dragging Image and Drop it into Drop Here Box***
[image: Take as an Object File]